# Deriving a formula for area of a triangle using vector cross product

Tags: derivatives, vectors, proof-explanation, cross-product

Using the vector cross product, how would I derive a formula for the area of a triangle with vertices: $$\\(x_0, y_0, z_0)\\(x_1, y_1, z_1)\\(x_2, y_2, z_2)  $$ in terms of only  $x_0, y_0, z_0, x_1, y_1, z_1, x_2, y_2, z_2. $

I would appreciate any help given, thank you very much!

Comment: Do you mean you want to prove that the cross product of the vectors is the area of the triangle, or do you want to know how you can find the area given the coordinates because the cross product is the answer to the second.

Comment: I wanted to derive a formula for the area of a triangle using the vector cross product with everything in terms of the vector components only.

Comment: You can find your answer (and explanations) here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TriangleArea.html Denoting the vectors you give above as the vertices A, B, and C, all you need in the formula from the www link  is say, vectors B-A and C-A or any of the other two possible pairs. The result (the area) is the same.

Comment: Do you remember the geometrical interpretation of the length of the cross product of two vectors?

Comment: As I remember, the magnitude of the cross product is the area of the parallelogram with the two vectors as the sides

Answer (score 1):

The length of the crossproduct equals the area of the parallelogram, spaned by its vectors.

$$A = \frac{1}{2} |v_1 \times v_2| $$ with $v_1 = (x_0 - x_1, y_0 - y_1, z_0 - z_1)^T$ and $v_1 = (x_0 - x_2, y_0 - y_2, z_0 - z_2)^T$

If you wonder what $|  | $ means: it is the length of vector inside. In our case, the length of the vector of the crossproduct.

Now take a pen and a paper, write this down and derive the formula yourself